# Is There A Chinese Version of Urban Slang Dictionary?

Tags: resources, slang, database, websites

Many questions on this site concern various modern slang/dialect usages that require fairly extensive (and sometimes still unsuccessful) searches through the web.  Every time I think about these questions, I wonder about whether, if I were a Chinese person dealing with similar weirdnesses in English, I would find [the Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com) very useful (I find it useful even as an English-speaking person dealing with all the weirdnesses of English).

Does such a crowdsourced "database" of colloquial Chinese usages exist on the Internet?  Is there any such good one-stop online place to do searches on Chinese slang?

Comment: Not that I know about. I even think that I should make one. As a native speaker, I encounter new slangs online very often as well. And I found that most of the time I got to Baidu them.

Comment: do it!  legions of miserable 老外 would be eternally grateful :)

Comment: Well there is a Chinese version of UD: http://zh.urbandictionary.com/ 

&&

China Smack's glossary: www.chinasmack.com/glossary

Comment: well that's disappointing, I thought I had an awesome new thing to work on. good to know the resource is there though. Thanks.

Comment: Aha! I thought there was no such a thing! Almost start creating one...good to know!

Comment: BTW, you should post it as an answer so people can know that.

Comment: @user3306356 ileonard is right- please post as answer. Free points!:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a Chinese version of UD: zh.urbandictionary.com && China Smack's glossary: www.chinasmack.com/glossary

China Digital Times also has a list, I'll update with that later.

---

[CDT: Sensitive Words Series](https://chinadigitaltimes.net/china/sensitive-words-series/)

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this website: www.liyuslang.com
I think it's pretty good. Was hoping to find other similar ones. Looks like there aren't many out there.